# How to get list of JSON navigations of a EF Core 7 entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have some models that are created in a `DBContext`. Some of them may have some navigation properties.
I get `IEntityType` of those models using this method:

```
var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
```

When I call `entityType.GetProperties()` it returns none of navigation fields of the entity.
Also when I call `entityType.GetNavigations()` it returns all navigation fields of the entity.
Some of those navigation fields are JSON fields and I wanna detect them in some of my practices.
I check all methods and properties of the returned type `INavigation`, but I can't find any related property or method that can specify JSON navigation filed.
In configuration of `DBContext` I used this code for configuring JSON field:

```
builder.OwnsOne(e => e.MyPropName, ownedNavigationBuilder => ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson());
```

This config works well to storing or querying purposes, but the main problem is "How can I find list of JSON navigation fields of an entity in EF Core 7"?

Comment: Why do you want that? A DbContext isn't a database model. All ORMs, not just EF Core, try to give the illusion of working with in-memory objects instead of relational tables. Entities aren't tables, they're in-memory objects or as close as possible to this. Where those entities map is part of the mapping configuration, not the entity itself. `builder.OwnsOne` is part of that mapping config and shouldn't affect application code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, In configuration, I use ToJson() for some navigation fields and it belongs to EF Core, so; You mean that EF Core doesn't have any solution to find those properties that I configured?

Comment: I mean `What are you trying to do`? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have a problem X and assume Y is the solution, so when that doesn't work you ask about Y, not the real problem X. On one hand, JSON columns are mapped to owned entities, which is why `OwnsOne` is used. That's not a navigation to another standalone entity. The `MyPropName` property is a complex property of the owning entity, not an independent object. It's the same as mapping 3 table columns to 1 owned Address type.

Comment: On the other hand, ORMs *don't* leak table information into the C# objects if they can help it. The application shouldn't care whether `Address` maps to one JSON column or 3 simple columns in the underlying table

Comment: Whether the owned type is mapped to JSON or multiple columns is part of the *mapping*, not the entity. You can use [GetTableMappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypeextensions.gettablemappings?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-relationalentitytypeextensions-gettablemappings(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-ientitytype)) on `EntityType` to get the column mapping info and check the each column's `TypeMapping` property for a `JsonTypeMapping`